# Which output from Circular Convolution is initially correct? The FFT convolution or the scipy signal wrap convolution

Tags: python, scipy, fft

Doing a circular convolution via the FFT VS via scipy convolve2d using "wrap" boundary settings gives the same results, but at different positions in the output matrix.

Of these two methods which has the positions initially correct (i.e which one should I shift to match the other) ?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import signal
from numpy.fft import ifft2, fft2

imgSize = 4
filtSize = 3
padFilt = imgSize - filtSize
testImg = np.random.uniform(0,1,(imgSize,imgSize))
filter = np.random.normal(0,3.0,(filtSize,filtSize))


circConv = scipy.signal.convolve2d(testImg, filter, boundary="wrap", mode="same")

filterFFT = np.pad(filter,((0,padFilt),(0,padFilt)),'constant')
fftConv = np.real(ifft2(fft2(testImg) * fft2(filterFFT)))

# Roll the FFT output to match the wrap output
fftConv = np.roll(fftConv, (-((filterFFT.shape[0] - 1) // 2), -((filterFFT.shape[1] - 1) // 2)), axis=(0, 1))
print(circConv)
print(fftConv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on where your coordinate origin is.
If it is top left go with fft.
If it is in the center go with convolve.

```
>>> a = (1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
>>> a = np.outer(a, a)
>>> a
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> np.real(ifft2(fft2(a) * fft2(a)))
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
>>> 
>>> a = (0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
>>> a = np.outer(a, a)
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> scipy.signal.convolve2d(a, a, boundary="wrap", mode="same")
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: In this instance of an image the origin is considered (0,0), the top left, by default?

Comment: @Kevinj22 in practice it will depend on your filter. For example if it is a Gaussian blur, where is the peak? If it's in the center, that's the origin, if the Gaussian appears to be cut into four quarters with the peak in the corners, then top left is the origin.